# ipython notebook: problems with matplotlib rc-file and custom css

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using a custom notebook theme according to this [tutorial](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/Carreau/posts/blob/master/Blog1.ipynb#The-answer-:-custom.css). Basically I entered: `ipython profile create customcss` in a command-line and modified the custom.css file in  `~/.ipython/profile_default/static/custom`

Additionally i tried to get rid of my personalizations and imports in the first cell of every notebook by writing a file called `00_my_imports.py` in the folder `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup`.

Unfortunately, following lines are not executed somehow (at least the plots do not look like in my rc-file specified):

```
'''
Import of my personal plot properties and functions, classes etc..
'''
if os.name == 'nt':
    sys.path.append('R:/acib/Projekte/dn/4.3_5.2/Microparticles/mypy')
    rc_file('R:..../plot_properties/dissertation.rc')
elif os.name == 'posix':
    sys.path.append('/home/moritz/prog/python/mypy/')
    rc_file('/home/moritz/..../dissertation.rc')
```

Any ideas why ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your path might be wrong - you're accessing the R drive, but then immediately trying to access the parent directory ("R:../plot...").

Comment: Misleading spelling. I did not want to show the whole path in public. Changed it to four dots

Comment: hey, I also just noticed that you created a custom profile called customcss, but then you edited the default profile.  This may be your issue.  Here's how it works:  Each profile is in that directory, 'profile_default', 'profile_customcss'.  When you start ipython, you can start it with whichever profile you want:  ipython --profile=customcss.  If you edited the default profile but then executed ipython with customcss, that's why your changes didn't show up.  I'm going to try setting that rc_file right now, I'll reply again with the result in case you or someone else is still trying to do this

Comment: One more hint:  if you are calling the magic function %matplotlib inline, it will overwrite a lot of the colors and settings, so that might be why yours aren't showing up.  Things like "pd.set_option('display.mpl_style', 'default')" will do the same

Comment: THX Tristan, I will check your comments and let you know if it worked.. I just tried to use the line rc_file('...') without the loop and it works. Additionall, I checked if the loop is executed and it is executed.